# bounded functions, norms

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

[image]

Instead of answering this question could someone possibly explain what I need to do? I don't fully understand what the question is asking, firstly $M$ has been fully defined so how do we know $|M|$? also where it says $m$ is a bounded function, does this imply we can take any bounded function? for example $\cos(x)$?

Comment: $\|M\|= \sup_{f \in B(\mathbb R), \|f\|_\infty ≤1} \| M(f) \|_\infty$. You can take any bounded function to get a well defined operator. It does not need to be continuous or anything. You can also take the $0$ function and see what happens if you like.

Comment: interesting, could you explain how you deduced what $||M||$ was?

Comment: Can't really be called a deduction, since this is the usual definition of the operator norm, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Comment: awesome this is very help, could you possibly explain part a?

Comment: To see $\|M\|≥\|m\|_\infty$, note that the constant function $1$ has norm $1$, and $\|M(1)\|_\infty = \|m \cdot 1\|_\infty = \|m\|_\infty$. To see that $\|M\|≤\|m\|_\infty$, note that $\|M(f)\|_\infty = \|m \cdot f \|_\infty ≤ \|m\|_\infty \|f\|_\infty$. If $\|f\|_\infty ≤1$, this means $\|M(f)\|_\infty ≤\|m\|_\infty$. (The observation $\|m \cdot f \|_\infty ≤ \|m\|_\infty \|f\|_\infty$ is a simpler exercise)

Comment: so proving $\|M\|≥\|m\|_\infty$ you let the bounded function be $1$? would we not be required to show this for arbitrary $f$?

Comment: The definition of $\|M\|$ involves a supremum, which is why you to show $≥$ you can consider an arbitrary $f$ with norm $≤1$. (In this comment arbitrary does not mean that $≥$ has to hold for all $f$, but rather if you pick one and $≥$ holds, then it also holds for the supremum)

Comment: No, $=$ holds. What function is $M(1)$?

Comment: $(M(1))\,(x) = m(x)\cdot 1(x) = m(x)$

Comment: ohhh of course, and because we have picked $f$ to be $1$ it shows $\|M\|≥\|m\|_\infty$

Comment: @s.harp could you possibly explain part b? ... maybe formulate it as an answer to avoid excess comments here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a):

$\|M\|$ is defined via

$$\|M\|:=\sup_{f \in B(\mathbb R),\ \|f\|_\infty ≤1} \|M(f)\|_\infty$$

Then since for example $\|M(1)\|=\|m\cdot 1\|_\infty = \|m\|_\infty$ and $\|M(f)\|=\|m\cdot f\|_\infty ≤ \|m\|_\infty \|f\|_\infty$ it follows that $\|M\| = \|m\|_\infty$.

For part b):

If $m$ has no zeros on $\mathbb R$, then the pointwise inverse $m^{-1}$ of $m$ exists. Note that:

$$m^{-1}(x)\cdot (m(x)^\mathstrut \cdot f(x)) = f(x)$$

for all $x$ and all $f$. So you would suppose the inverse of $M$ to be given by the multiplication of $m^{-1}$ (which we will from now one denote by the operator $N$, in other words $(N(f))\, (x) := m^{-1}(x)\cdot f(x)$).

But this is not true, consider for example $m(x)=e^{-x^2}$, then $m^{-1}(x) = e^{x^2}$ which is not a bounded function, and application of $N$ on a bounded function need not return a bounded function. (For example $N(1)=m^{-1}$)

If $m^{-1}$ is bounded, then $N$ is once again well defined as a linear map $B(\mathbb R) \to B(\mathbb R)$, and $N$ is the inverse of $M$. $m^{-1}$ is bounded iff there exists a $c>0$ so that $0<c<|m(x)|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, that is if $m$ is bounded from below.

Comment: have you denote the operator $N$ as the inverse of $M$ which is $M\cdot m^{-1}$?

Comment: $(N(f))\, (x) := m^{-1}(x)\cdot f(x)$

Comment: i don't understand how this shows the second part of part b? "for which functions $m$ is $M^{-1} \in L(B(\mathbb{R}))$

Comment: If $m^{-1}$ is bounded, then $N$ is a linear map: $B(\mathbb R) \to B(\mathbb R)$, and also $N=M^{-1}$. If $m^{-1}$ is not bounded then $M$ has no inverse in $\mathcal L(B(\mathbb R))$, since eg $M M^{-1}(1) = 1$ should hold if the inverse existed, but if $m^{-1}$ is not bounded, there exists no bounded function $f$ so that $m(x)f(x)=1$ for all $x$, ie $M^{-1}(1)$ is not a bounded function.